# I am converting YOLOV7 .pt to tflite and stumble upon this problem

Tags: tflite, yolov7, tf2onnx

I'm trying to convert YOLOV7 model to mobile using this command line  `onnx-tf convert -i yolov7.onnx  -o /yolov7/` and I'm getting an error message that I'm struggling to understand. The error message is:

`ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are [a] and [b] for '{{node Add_3}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT](concat_3/concat, ExpandDims_2)' with input shapes: [1,160,160,64], [1,1,1,64,32,3,3].`

I'm not sure what this error message means or how to fix it. Can anyone help me understand what's going on and how to resolve this error?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!